# Unable to match a specific regex with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, pipe, read

I have a `txt` file with content as such:

```
Adedunmola Okikiola Adewole        512.035
215−39                    ^M
Ademir Cleto de Oliveira                 055.735
445−13                    ^M
Adilson Wagner Gandu                   559.995
780−28                    ^M
```

When I run my script,

```bsh
 #!/usr/bin/bash

 file="$@"

 while IFS= read -r cmd; do
     printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
 done < "$file"
```

```bsh
./readline.sh list.txt
```

I get outputs formatted as such:

```
Yves Levi Paixao Lapa                   022.485 165"24
Yvin Miguel Juanico Carvalho         623.200 765"20
Yzis Silva Lima Santos                   372.341 215"39
Zilmara de Nazare Lucas Pimentel   282.147 230"44
```

But, I can't make grep work with the following pattern:

```bsh
./readline.sh list.txt | grep "230\"44"
```

Which is a code for the course. In this exemplary output, I expected it should give me, at least, the line:

```bsh
Zilmara de Nazare Lucas Pimentel   282.147 230"44
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Print:
[image]

Link to the txt file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1azr_GSB2rBHd9dPzx43vrRdqkxkWb60G/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT2:**

Changing the file encoding to `utf-8` make the output equal to what vim or emacs initially showed. But, still, I can't successfully grep "230-44", for example.

Comment: Are you sure that shell script produces the output you show?

Comment: Yes, I can show you prints

Comment: Your script outputs the file as it is, it doesn't change the format. `./readline.sh list.txt` is functionally equivalent to `cat list.txt`. The `grep` command is fine and works **IF** the pattern is actually in the file.

Comment: I changed the file encoding to utf-8. And, now the `cat` output is equal to the shown in the file. But, I can't successfully grep "230-44", for example

Comment: inspect the file by piping it into `| od -bc` to see what's really there. Then you can match it.

Comment: It's likely that the input file is a DOS text file that needs to be converted to a Unix text file (e.g. with `dos2unix`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `-` on grep, when the text was actually other character (which get's converted when I paste it to stack overflow)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried with grep and sed worked fine

```
./readline.sh list.txt |grep '230\"44'

output: Zilmara de Nazare Lucas Pimentel   282.147 230"44


  ./readline.sh list.txt |sed -n '/230\"44/p'

output: Zilmara de Nazare Lucas Pimentel   282.147 230"44
```